# Only allow domain logins using TeamViewer

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, teamviewer

**TLDR**

How do I setup [TeamViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) to only allow logins that authenticate through Windows ([domain controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller)), while disallowing any other login method?

---

I recently started a system administrator job where TeamViewer is used pretty frequently. Another administrator recently left, and the concern is they still have access to all our systems due to how TeamViewer works. I want to migrate the entire environment to domain authentication.

The documentation shows that setting up Windows authentication (domain) is easy, but I want to be sure that it is the only way to be authenticated with a TeamViewer session here. I cannot yet find anything which explicitly says this.

We have licensing for TeamViewer 5 and 6, I think. Right now we have 7 in the environment, but I think most are in a trial version, so I am likely to revert to 5 or 6.